# How to add RPA.Desktop library in Robot Framewok

Tags: robotframework, ui-automation, pyautogui, rpa

I am new in Robot Framework and i am using this for testing desktop application.

I have added RPA.Windows with
**Library        RPA.Windows** (which is working fine)
but when i added
**Library        RPA.Desktop** or
**Library        RPA.Desktop.OperatingSystem**

It shows an error
( **Unresolved library: RPA.Desktop.
Error generating libspec:
Importing library 'RPA.Desktop' failed: Module 'RPA' does not contain 'Desktop'.
Consider adding the needed paths to the "robot.pythonpath" setting
and calling the "Robot Framework: Clear caches and restart" action.robotframework** )

Anyonce can tell me how can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add Environment variable solve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).